# trying to get the parent of this in each statement

Tags: jquery, if-statement, parent, each

Have whats probably a simple problem with using parent in if and each statements

I have some html that looks like:

```
<li><span class="image"><img src="img1.jpg"></span></li>
<li><span class="image"><img src="img2.jpg"></span></li>
<li><span class="image"><img src=""></span></li>
<li><span class="image"><img src=""></span></li>
```

With my JQuery I have an if statement within an each statement as follows:

```
$(".image").each(function() { 
    var $imgsrc = $(this).find("img").attr("src").length;

    if($imgsrc < 1) {
        $('.image').parent().addClass('nodisplay');
    }    
});
```

I want the to add the class 'nodisplay' be added to the `<li>`'s whose images have no src.

Problem is the code above affects all `<li>`'s. If I replace `$('.image')` with `$('this')` it no longer works at all.

I have also tried `closest('li')` instead of `parent()` to no avail.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: you're opening a span and you're closing a div?

Comment: oops - my mistake in transcribing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('li').has(".image img[src='']").addClass('nodisplay');
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lr9s9/)

Answer (score 2):

you should be writing `$(this)` instead of `$('this')`